# I want to click my list item in random but can't

Tags: javascript, list, click, html-lists, addeventlistener

I would like to add a click event to my list of items. It's a TO-DO-LIST, so a list item should have a line-through style whenever I click it. However, I can't get it right. The console always says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: togList.addEventListener is not a function
```

---

```
var togList = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

function togglesOnOff() {
        togList.classList.toggle("done");
}

togList.addEventListener("click", togglesOnOff);
```

Comment: One thing to check is maybe the script is being run before the HTML element is processed.

Comment: oh..I made sure the script is on the last part. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because `getElementsByTagName` doesn't return an element it returns a [collection of elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

so, you need to loop over the collection:

```js
var togList = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

function togglesOnOff() {
  this.classList.toggle("done");
}

Array.from(togList).forEach(item => item.addEventListener("click", togglesOnOff));
```

```css
.done {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item one</li>
  <li>Item two</li>
  <li>Item three</li>
</ul>
```

You will also need to change the function to use the current element to toggle the class. To do so, we just change `togList` to `this`.

Comment: Thank you for your very fast answer. I just want to add something. The code only applied to the original list item, whenever I added items through a textbox, the toggle function won't apply to them.

Comment: You need to add the event to them when they are created.